# Customize multiple colors on one layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to customize a layout with multiple colors (like the image below).
This is what I did, but it is just half of the screen. I want the background to fit with all devices.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="#93DF46" android:gravity="left" android:width="400dp"/>
    <item android:drawable="#2AAE84" android:gravity="left" android:width="300dp"/>
    <item android:drawable="#CC1E4F" android:gravity="left" android:width="200dp"/>
    <item android:drawable="#0040FF" android:gravity="left" android:width="100dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

[image: Image with vertical color palette]

Answer (score 0):

dont use fixed dp

Create a new XML drawable resource file (e.g., custom_background.xml)

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- First color (leftmost) -->
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="25%" />
            <solid android:color="#93DF46" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Second color -->
    <item android:left="25%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="25%" />
            <solid android:color="#2AAE84" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Third color -->
    <item android:left="50%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="25%" />
            <solid android:color="#CC1E4F" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Fourth color (rightmost) -->
    <item android:left="75%">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <size android:width="25%" />
            <solid android:color="#0040FF" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_background">
    <!-- Your layout content -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's red at "25%"